# vim align columns using Align or Tabularize (Verilog)

Tags: vim, alignment, verilog

I am trying to use either Align or Tabularize to take the following code:

```
   // UDW
   input  [UDW_WIDTH-1:0]     udw_data;
   input [TYPE_WIDTH-1:0]     udw_type;
   input                      udw_valid;
   output                     udw_ready;
   // UniClkPktGen
   input [UTW_DATA_W-1:0]     utw_data_in;
   input                      utw_valid_in;
   input [FREQOFFSET_W-1:0]   freqOffset;
   input [ACCDELAY_W-1:0]     accDelay;
   // RIF                     
   input [31:0]                    rif_add_bus;
   input [31:0]                    rif_data_wr;
   input [3:0]                  rif_byte_en;
   input                         rif_wr;
   input                         rif_rd;
   output [31:0]                   rif_data_rd;
   output                        rif_ack;
```

To be aligned to this:

```
   // UDW
   input  [UDW_WIDTH-1:0]     udw_data;
   input  [TYPE_WIDTH-1:0]    udw_type;
   input                      udw_valid;
   output                     udw_ready;
   // UniClkPktGen
   input  [UTW_DATA_W-1:0]    utw_data_in;
   input                      utw_valid_in;
   input  [FREQOFFSET_W-1:0]  freqOffset;
   input  [ACCDELAY_W-1:0]    accDelay;
   // RIF                     
   input  [31:0]              rif_add_bus;
   input  [31:0]              rif_data_wr;
   input  [3:0]               rif_byte_en;
   input                      rif_wr;
   input                      rif_rd;
   output [31:0]              rif_data_rd;
   output                     rif_ack;
```

As you can see, sometimes there will be square brackets before the variable name, some time won't. Comments could be in the middle, I would like them to be ignored. I want to keep the space before the input/output.
I tried some regex, but couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: if a other plugin is an option for you, then there is always [easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align)

Comment: You could just use `visual block` to move the text.

Comment: I will try to use the easy align.
Using visual block is not automatic (and that's what I am currently doing), I am trying to find a fast way to do it. There are a lot of lines like that in all the files that I am working. Completely mundane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have managed to do it with easy-align (thanks Doktor OSwaldo).
I used the advance examples :
https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md

I took this code and added it to ~/.vim/autoload/easy_align.vim (taken from EXAMPLES.md above).

```
let g:easy_align_delimiters['d'] = {
\ 'pattern': ' \ze\S\+\s*[;=]',
\ 'left_margin': 0, 'right_margin': 0
\ }
```

I don't fully understand the pattern so I will not try to explain it.
But it works :)

Comment: The pattern matches the last space before (`\ze`) the pattern `\S\+\s*[;=]'`. `\S\+\s*[;=]'` matches at least one non-whitespace character sequence (`\S\+`) followed by optional whitespace (`\s*`) then followed by either `;` or `=` (`[;=]`). For more help see `:h /\ze`, `:h /\+`, `:h /\S`, `/\s`, and `:h /collection`.